# Create a summary variable getting results from multiple variables checking against multiple lists in a dictionary in Pandas/Python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, iteration, multiple-columns, scanning

```
DXCODE1     DXCODE2     DXCODE3
A1          A2          B2
C2          D3          NaN
B2          C2          A1

DXCODE_DICTIONARY = {'Code_Apple':['A1', 'A2', 'A3', 'A4'],
    'Code_Banana':['B1', 'B2', 'B3'],
    'Code_Cat':['C1', 'C2', 'C3']}

DXCODE1     DXCODE2     DXCODE3         DXCODE_SUMMARY
A1          A2          B2              ['Apple', 'Apple', 'Banana']
C2          D3          NaN             ['Cat']
B2          C2          A1              ['Banana', 'Cat', 'Apple']
```

The above describes the challenge I am trying to solve in Pandas. In the df, I have three DXCODE variables. My end goal is to create a DXCODE_SUMMARY variable to summarize the DXCODE1 to DXCODE3. For each row, I want to check across the three variables. For example, for DXCODE1, I want to check it against the DXCODE_DICTIONARY, if it is within the list of 'Code_Apple', I want to tag it with 'Apple' (derive from the dictionary key), then it will check against the list of 'Code_Banana', if it is within the list, I want 'Banana' to be added into the list in DXCODE_SUMMARY. Once DXCODE1 is checked against all the lists in DXCODE_DICTIONARY, the same will be done for DXCODE2, then for DXCODE3.

Edits: Added 'A4' on the 'Code_Apple' list.

Answer (score 0):

Try to modify your `dict` then we do `map` and `groupby` `apply` with `list`

```
dictdf=pd.DataFrame(DXCODE_DICTIONARY).melt()
newdict=dict(zip(dictdf.value,dictdf.variable))

df.apply(lambda x : x.map(newdict)).stack().groupby(level=0).apply(list)
Out[1005]: 
0    [Code_Apple, Code_Apple, Code_Banana]
1                               [Code_Cat]
2      [Code_Banana, Code_Cat, Code_Apple]
dtype: object
```

Comment: Could you make your solution more generalizable? Your solution only works when DXCODE_DICTIONARY is of certain number of rows and columns. I got the 'ValueError: arrays must all be same length' error when I make the 'Code Apple" as ['A1', 'A2', 'A3', 'A4'].